# Connecting to many databases at once in mongo/mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We are trying to connect to 1500 databases using mongoose but it's too slow to create 1500 connection with 1500 DB using this command

```
mongoose.createConnection(url);
```

the 1500 DB are on the same database server.
it took more than 50 minutes to establish these connections.

Is there any way to decrease the amount of time or is there a way to connect to the 1500 DB at once as they are on the same server?

Comment: Why do you need that many dbs? Is there a reason you can't separate your data in collections instead? Also, if you are sharding your dbs, you don't need to connect to each shard. Short of a loop, I can't think of any perf improvement without reducing the number of dbs.

Comment: thank you but it's required to have that number of DBs.

Comment: I admit I am interested in what use case lead to such a tremendous number of DB, and how you will be able to maintain all thoses connections. Since `createConnection` is asynchronous, you should be able to use `async` to speed up the connection, but I m not sure it will have much of a impact.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [async](https://github.com/caolan/async):

```
'use strict';
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    async = require('async'),
    dbsUrl = [
    'mongodb://url1',
    //...
    'mongodb://url15000',
];

async.map(dbsUrl, (url, callback) => {
    let conn = mongoose.createConnection();
    conn.once('error', (err) => {
        callback(err);
    });
    conn.once('connected', () => {
        callback(null, conn);
    });
}, (err, dbs) => {
    //If a error happenned, it will callback immediately
    //Else, dbs will now be a array of connections
});
```

I do not know about the performance for such number of connection though.